# How do i integrate a browser in my tk application?

Tags: python, browser, tkinter

I am writing a Python program and want at some point to load HTML pages from the web and display them, in particular the support forum section/news section of my program. How can I easily integrate that into my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to switch toolkits - Gtk+/Qt both have support for WebKit rendering engine. Both toolkits also have Python bindings support.

Comment: but i have almost a working gui created in tkinter with page. i am planning to distribute with py2exe

Comment: I can assure you that it would be easier to rewrite the app in other toolkit than to write a browser engine. Tough luck though. :(

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has no native support for displaying HTML. With a little bit of work you can download the raw html, do a little text manipulation (assuming it's mostly plain text and a few tags for bold, headers, etc), and display it in a text widget. If it's well formed xhtml you can use an xml parser to pull out the relevant data and give it appropriate formatting.

If the pages have embeded images, or use css or javascript, the problem becomes exponentially harder to the point of not being practical.